# how to reconnect to websocket client after close/disconnect using promises?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, websocket

I have created a websocket client example using promises by using one of previous examples on stack overflow. It is working properly except if I close the connection after logout, then it is not able to reconnect on next login. It shows "WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state". I am posting the whole code. Can anyone please inform me where I am doing wrong?

```
class TheWebSocket {
    get _clientPromise() {
        let socket = new WebSocket(wsConnectionString);

        let openWebSocket = () => {
            socket.onopen = () => {
                Cookies.set("websocketConnected", true);
                console.info(messages.websocketConnected);
            };
        };

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
            socket.onmessage = (message) => arrayBufferToInt(message.data);

            socket.onopen = () => {
                Cookies.set("websocketConnected", true);
                console.info(messages.websocketConnected);
                resolve(socket);
            };

            socket.onclose = () => {
                Cookies.set("websocketConnected", false);
                console.info(messages.websocketDisconnected);
                openWebSocket();
            };

            socket.onerror = (error) => {
                var errorText = null;

                switch (error.currentTarget?.readyState) {
                    case 0:
                        errorText = messages.websocketReadyState0;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        errorText = messages.websocketReadyState2;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        errorText = messages.websocketReadyState3;
                        break;
                }

                Cookies.set("websocketConnected", false);
                console.error(`WebSocket Error [Reason: ${errorText}]`);
                openWebSocket();
                reject(error);
            };
        });
    }

    get clientPromise() {
        if (!this.promise) {
            this.promise = this._clientPromise;
        }
        return this.promise;
    }
}

globalThis.websocketSingleton = new TheWebSocket();

const sendMessage = (action, source, payload) => {
    globalThis.websocketSingleton.clientPromise
        .then((socket) => {
            if (action != "disconnect") {
                console.log(`${action == "Unsubscribe" ? `-- ${action}` : action} ${source} =`, payload);

                const data = JSON.stringify({
                    a: payload.a,
                    x: payload.x,
                    v: payload.v,
                });

                socket.send(data);       // Error comes here ...
            } else {
                console.info(messages.websocketClosed);
                socket.close();
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};
```

I tried using functions and other few tutorials but all in vain.